# Android - How can I using HttpURLConnection to get bitmaps from URLs that is redirected to a mobile version?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, user-agent, httpurlconnection

I have developed an android app, that use 'HttpURLConnection' to get bitmaps from URLs.

The code works fine with a general URL. Unfortunately, I have found one problem that cannot solve it.

The problem is when the URL is on the file sharing's site, it will detect the user-agent. If the user-agent shows that the device is mobile, it will redirect to the mobile version page with lots of HTML tags. So, I cannot get the bitmap.

I have tried to change the user-agent in many ways, but it is not work at all.

FYI: With the same code, some bitmaps, with a general URL, can be gotten. But when it is on the site that has a redirection code, it will not work.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thank you very much.

**Here is my code:**

```
String imgUrl = "http://upic.me/i/lj/0avatar.jpg";
Bitmap img = null;
try{
    URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty( "User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4" );
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I open this URL (http://upic.me/i/lj/0avatar.jpg) via the chrome browser in Android, it redirect to another URL (http://upic.me/show/37096796).

Comment: Your code is working. I am getting the bitmap

Comment: @SunilMishra Thanks for your help. Yep, that's work. But some websites have an user-agent detection code, that will redirect to another link if your device is a mobile, not a desktop. As I told you above, the example site of my problem is http://upic.me/i/lj/0avatar.jpg, if it's a mobile screen, it will redirect to http://upic.me/show/37096796.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

[AndroidSmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/)

SmartImageView is a drop-in replacement for Android’s standard ImageView which additionally allows images to be loaded from URLs or the user’s contact address book. Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your suggested library, that's a very good one. But still have same problem.